# Curl to Python Conversion

Tags: python, django, api, request, converters

I'm trying to use the Twitch API in a Django [python] web application. I want to send a request and get information back, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json' -X GET \
    https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel
```

How do I convert this python?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? This is a simple GET request with one header, so you should be able to find all of the information you need with a search engine.

Comment: As a starting place, see [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen). You could instead install a third-party library like `requests` or even `pycurl`, but for something this trivial, you don't need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the builtin [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> req = urllib2.Request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel')
>>> req.add_header('Accept', 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json')
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> content = resp.read()
```

If you're using Python 3.x, the module is called [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), but otherwise you can do everything the same.

You could also use a third-party library for HTTP, like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/), which has a simpler API:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel', 
                     headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json'})
>>> print(r.status_code)
422 # <- on my machine, YMMV
>>> print(r.text)
{"status":422,"message":"Channel 'test_channel' is not available on Twitch",
 "error":"Unprocessable Entity"}
```

Comment: You could, but why? A trivial case like this is just as easy with `urlopen`, which comes with Python.

Comment: @abarnert: You are right, it's just that I think `requests` has a bit nicer API. Anyway - added an example with `urllib2`, too.

Comment: I agree that for anything between trivial cases and really nasty ones (where you need to, e.g., hook into the socket options), `requests` is definitely easier—sometimes much, much easier. I only suggested sticking with `urlopen` because this is one of those trivial cases. Anyway, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use urllib2 for my api requests in (blocking) python apps.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> req = urllib2.Request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel', None, {'Accept':'application/vnd.twitchtv.vs+json'})
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

You can then access the text returned with `response.read()`. From there you can parse the JSON with your preferred library, though I generally just use `json.loads(response.read())`.

I would keep in mind, though, that this is for 2.7, if you are using python 3 the libraries have been moved around and this can be found in `urllib.request`